# How to block Actionscript 3.0 embedded YouTube videos ads?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube

I follow this steps and manage to play videos on my flash movie, http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html

Now I wonder if is possible to block the ads? any help will be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: You might find a way to do what you want. But keep in mind that *most likely violates* the API's terms of use...

Comment: Yep. That's expressly prohibited. "II. Prohibitions: ... 7. modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the YouTube player;". http://code.google.com/intl/en-419/apis/youtube/terms.html

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

1. try to overlay them with some divs
2. decompile player swf and find ad id, and to remove it outside from swfloader